# Python de-aggregation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set which is aggregated between two dates and I want to de-aggregate it daily by dividing total number with days between these dates.
As a sample

```
StoreID Date_Start    Date_End     Total_Number_of_sales
78       12/04/2015    17/05/2015    79089
80       12/04/2015    17/05/2015    79089
```

The data set I want is:

```
StoreID Date         Number_Sales 
78         12/04/2015    79089/38(as there are 38 days in between)
78         13/04/2015    79089/38(as there are 38 days in between) 
78         14/04/2015    79089/38(as there are 38 days in between)
78         ...
78         17/05/2015    79089/38(as there are 38 days in between)
```

Any help would be useful.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want but you can try this (I've added another imaginary row):

```
import datetime as dt
df = pd.DataFrame({'date_start':['12/04/2015','17/05/2015'],
                   'date_end':['18/05/2015','10/06/2015'],
                   'sales':[79089, 1000]})

df['date_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_start'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
df['date_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_end'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
df['days_diff'] = (df['date_end'] - df['date_start']).dt.days


master_df = pd.DataFrame(None)
for row in df.index:
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start=df['date_start'].iloc[row],
                          end = df['date_end'].iloc[row],
                          freq='d'))
    new_df['number_sales'] = df['sales'].iloc[row] / df['days_diff'].iloc[row]
    master_df = pd.concat([master_df, new_df], axis=0)
```

First convert string dates to datetime objects (so you can calculate number of days in between ranges), then create a new index based on the date range, and divide sales. The loop sticks each row of your dataframe into an "expanded" dataframe and then concatenates them into one master dataframe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem is that I want to do it for all store ids so it needs to loop all stores, so final df should also include them ,any ideas?

Comment: [Never call DataFrame.append or pd.concat inside a for-loop. It leads to quadratic copying.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36489724/1422451)

Answer (score 1):

What about creating a new dataframe?

```
start = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Start'].values[0], dayfirst=True)
end = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_End'].values[0], dayfirst=True)
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=start, end=end, freq='D')
res = pd.DataFrame(df['Total_Number_of_sales'].values[0]/len(idx), index=idx, columns=['Number_Sales'])
```

yields

```
In[42]: res.head(5)
Out[42]: 
            Number_Sales
2015-04-12   2196.916667
2015-04-13   2196.916667
2015-04-14   2196.916667
2015-04-15   2196.916667
2015-04-16   2196.916667
```

If you have multiple stores (according to your comment and edit), then you *could* loop over all rows, calculate sales and concatenate the resulting dataframes afterwards.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Store_ID': [78, 78, 80],
    'Date_Start': ['12/04/2015', '18/05/2015', '21/06/2015'],
                   'Date_End': ['17/05/2015', '10/06/2015', '01/07/2015'],
                   'Total_Number_of_sales': [79089., 50000., 25000.]})

to_concat = []
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    start = pd.to_datetime(row['Date_Start'], dayfirst=True)
    end = pd.to_datetime(row['Date_End'], dayfirst=True)
    idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=start, end=end, freq='D')
    sales = [row['Total_Number_of_sales']/len(idx)] * len(idx)
    id = [row['Store_ID']] * len(idx)
    res = pd.DataFrame({'Store_ID': id, 'Number_Sales':sales}, index=idx)
    to_concat.append(res)

res = pd.concat(to_concat)
```

There are definitley more elegant solutions, have a look for example at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43832484/expanding-a-dataframe-based-on-start-and-end-columns-speed).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem is that I want to do it for all store ids so it needs to loop all stores, any ideas?

Comment: Are the start and end dates the same for all stores?

Comment: No they are different. And same store can have different start and end dates as these are aggregated values for some time and within longer period of time, store has multiple rows.

Answer (score 1):

Consider building a list of data frames with the `DataFrame` constructor iterating through each row of main data frame. Each iteration will expand a sequence of days from *Start_Date* to end of range with needed sales division of total sales by difference of days:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

txt = '''StoreID Date_Start    Date_End     Total_Number_of_sales
78       12/04/2015    17/05/2015    79089
80       12/04/2015    17/05/2015    89089'''

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+", parse_dates=[1, 2], dayfirst=True)
df['Diff_Days'] = (df['Date_End'] - df['Date_Start']).dt.days

def calc_days_sales(row): 
    long_df = pd.DataFrame({'StoreID': row['StoreID'],
                            'Date': [row['Date_Start'] + timedelta(days=i) 
                                          for i in range(row['Diff_Days']+1)],
                            'Number_Sales': row['Total_Number_of_sales'] / row['Diff_Days']})    
    return long_df

df_list = [calc_days_sales(row) for i, row in df.iterrows()]

final_df = pd.concat(df_list).reindex(['StoreID', 'Date', 'Number_Sales'], axis='columns')

print(final_df.head(10))
#    StoreID       Date  Number_Sales
# 0       78 2015-04-12   2259.685714
# 1       78 2015-04-13   2259.685714
# 2       78 2015-04-14   2259.685714
# 3       78 2015-04-15   2259.685714
# 4       78 2015-04-16   2259.685714
# 5       78 2015-04-17   2259.685714
# 6       78 2015-04-18   2259.685714
# 7       78 2015-04-19   2259.685714
# 8       78 2015-04-20   2259.685714
# 9       78 2015-04-21   2259.685714
```

*reindex at end not needed for Python 3.6 since data frame's input dictionary will be ordered.*